# How to deal with potential employer forgetting about my resume?

Tags: recruitment

I recently applied for a job, providing resume and a written recommendation. When planning the time for interview, i am being asked once again to provide my resume. After asking humbly, i discover that my potential employer has forgotten/missed that i sent it the first place.

Obviously the situation puts me off (I should probably add that i'm totally fine with others forgetting, however i am unsure the person has read my resume at all), but my question is how you would recommend handling the situation? In my mind i could either address it or ignore it, but either option doesn't feel very good.

Answer (score 9):

Stuff happens. Resumes get misplaced. Or they get sent to the HR department, who forgets to provide them to the hiring manager. Or the hiring manager forgets to send them to HR. Or the person who sets up the interview isn't the same person you originally applied to. This is all normal in any company.

Your only reasonable response is to say "Yes, no problem." and provide the resume again. This is especially true if you actually want the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the interview and ultimately the job simply provide the resume again as they have requested.  You can take this into consideration if they extend an offer to you but I wouldn't consider it a big deal.

Comment: Exactly, also remember that recruiters are people too and that they probably have a lot of candidates and resumes and sometimes information get lost or difficult to find. If you really want to job, lend to them, make their job to hire you easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make a big deal out of it.

In fact, I would say that *YOU* are the one in the wrong.  When I interview, I try to have 4 copies of the resume that I submitted (as I tweak them for each application) with me so that others who may have been invited to interview me at the last minute, or were invited during the interview as it progressed (yes, it happens) can each have their own copy.

Remember - you're trying to SELL them on hiring you.  You have talent/skills/ability, and they have money.  You're trying to get them to give you their money in trade for your work.  Have you ever encountered a salesman who would only let you have a single brochure?